# Is White automation tool thread safe?

Tags: c#, white-framework

I would like to perform a GUI automation tasks. I need to open several GUI windows and automate them all at onnce. My plan is to put each window on a separate thread and have White automation tool do some automation. My question can I do this without creating custom code to manage threads?

Comment: There's not a lot of global shared state with exception of `CoreAppXmlConfiguration` being a singleton. However, there is usually only one mouse pointer, for example. You would have to have some locking around access to those calls if you wanted it to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, the constraints are PHYSICAL.

To illustrate the issue, if you connect multiple keyboards/mice to your machine, then get multiple people to try and perform tests at the same time you will have a very hard time. Because you can only have a single mouse and focus on one application at the same time.

White cannot get around these physical limitations. No matter how much custom code you write.

Comment: Hi Jake, I figured this out by using .NET semaphore class.